# fill blanks in a column on specific conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df1:

```
Site    cells   technology  npv
T21079  G21079A UMTS900 76
T21079  G21079B UMTS900 
T21079  G21079C UMTS900 
T21079  U21079A UMTS2100    6
T21079  U21079B UMTS2100    8
T21079  U21079C UMTS2100    0
T21079  V21079A UMTS2100    6
T21079  V21079B UMTS2100    8
T21079  V21079C UMTS2100    0
T42406  G42406A UMTS900 23
T42406  G42406B UMTS900 56
T42406  G42406C UMTS900 12
T42406  U42406A UMTS2100    
T42406  U42406B UMTS2100    
T42406  U42406C UMTS2100    
T42406  V42406A UMTS2100    465
T42406  V42406B UMTS2100    466
T42406  V42406C UMTS2100    467
T42406  W42406A UMTS2100    
T42406  W42406B UMTS2100    7
T10003  G10003A UMTS900 
T10003  G10003B UMTS900 
T42406  W42406C UMTS2100    
T15805  G15805A UMTS900 369
T15805  G15805B UMTS900 370
T15805  G15805C UMTS900 371
T15805  U15805A UMTS2100    369
T15805  U15805B UMTS2100    
T15805  U15805C UMTS2100    
T15805  W15805A UMTS2100    369
T15805  W15805B UMTS2100    370
T15805  W15805C UMTS2100    371
```

I want dataframe df2 such that I want to fill the blanks in "npv" column based on the some conditions.

The conditions are first consider the cell that has blank "npv". if any other cell with same technology has same site name and if the last letter of the cell matches e.g. V42406A & W42406A, then copy the "npv" of V42406A to W42406A. 
If in the site, no other cells are in the same technology ending with same last letter, then copy the value from other technology cell in the same site having the same last letter

> e.g. G21079B & U21079B, then copy the "npv" of G21079B to U21079B.

If no other cell is in the site ending with same last letter in the site, then leave it blank. 
Hence my resultant dataframe df2 should have something like this:

```
Site    cells   technology  npv
T21079  G21079A UMTS900 76
T21079  G21079B UMTS900 8
T21079  G21079C UMTS900 0
T21079  U21079A UMTS2100    6
T21079  U21079B UMTS2100    8
T21079  U21079C UMTS2100    0
T21079  V21079A UMTS2100    6
T21079  V21079B UMTS2100    8
T21079  V21079C UMTS2100    0
T42406  G42406A UMTS900 23
T42406  G42406B UMTS900 56
T42406  G42406C UMTS900 12
T42406  U42406A UMTS2100    465
T42406  U42406B UMTS2100    466
T42406  U42406C UMTS2100    467
T42406  V42406A UMTS2100    465
T42406  V42406B UMTS2100    466
T42406  V42406C UMTS2100    467
T42406  W42406A UMTS2100    465
T42406  W42406B UMTS2100    7
T10003  G10003A UMTS900 
T10003  G10003B UMTS900 
T42406  W42406C UMTS2100    467
T15805  G15805A UMTS900 369
T15805  G15805B UMTS900 370
T15805  G15805C UMTS900 371
T15805  U15805A UMTS2100    369
T15805  U15805B UMTS2100    370
T15805  U15805C UMTS2100    371
T15805  W15805A UMTS2100    369
T15805  W15805B UMTS2100    370
T15805  W15805C UMTS2100    371
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with new Series created by last letter of `cells` with forward and back filling `NaN`s by [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) and [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html):

```
last= df['cells'].str[-1]
df['npv'] = df.groupby(['Site','technology',last])['npv'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
df['npv'] = df.groupby(['Site', last])['npv'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

---

```
print (df)
      Site    cells technology    npv
0   T21079  G21079A    UMTS900   76.0
1   T21079  G21079B    UMTS900    8.0
2   T21079  G21079C    UMTS900    0.0
3   T21079  U21079A   UMTS2100    6.0
4   T21079  U21079B   UMTS2100    8.0
5   T21079  U21079C   UMTS2100    0.0
6   T21079  V21079A   UMTS2100    6.0
7   T21079  V21079B   UMTS2100    8.0
8   T21079  V21079C   UMTS2100    0.0
9   T42406  G42406A    UMTS900   23.0
10  T42406  G42406B    UMTS900   56.0
11  T42406  G42406C    UMTS900   12.0
12  T42406  U42406A   UMTS2100  465.0
13  T42406  U42406B   UMTS2100  466.0
14  T42406  U42406C   UMTS2100  467.0
15  T42406  V42406A   UMTS2100  465.0
16  T42406  V42406B   UMTS2100  466.0
17  T42406  V42406C   UMTS2100  467.0
18  T42406  W42406A   UMTS2100  465.0
19  T42406  W42406B   UMTS2100    7.0
20  T10003  G10003A    UMTS900    NaN
21  T10003  G10003B    UMTS900    NaN
22  T42406  W42406C   UMTS2100  467.0
23  T15805  G15805A    UMTS900  369.0
24  T15805  G15805B    UMTS900  370.0
25  T15805  G15805C    UMTS900  371.0
26  T15805  U15805A   UMTS2100  369.0
27  T15805  U15805B   UMTS2100  370.0
28  T15805  U15805C   UMTS2100  371.0
29  T15805  W15805A   UMTS2100  369.0
30  T15805  W15805B   UMTS2100  370.0
31  T15805  W15805C   UMTS2100  371.0
```

Comment: this solution is ok.. but small issue in it.. it applies for other columns that are present in the excel..  i want only for "npv" column